# Python - readline() loop placing all lines into same value slot in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io, readline

I'm trying to create a dictionary of city names that can be accessed using numbers 0-99. I have a txt document where I'm reading the city names from, and I'm using python's readline() in a loop to enter each city into the dictionary. For some reason, my loop creates a list in the first value slot of the dictionary and the list contains all the city names, whereas I want each city to correspond to a different number in the dictionary. Why isn't the loop going onto the next key of the dictionary and entering the city in the next value slot?

Here's my chunk of code:

```
i = 0
cities = {}
inFile = open('cities.txt','r')

while i < 100:
    str = inFile.readline()
    str = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in inFile]
    cities[i] = str
    i += 1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the use of `str = inFile.readline()`, if you are not using `str`, but replacing that in the very next line?

Comment: str is a keyword in python.

Comment: The next line doesn't replace str but just strips off any unnecessary characters at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly iterate on each file line in Python. And it seems what you really need is a list of cities, not a dictionary.

So what you need is probably something like:

```
cities = []
with open("cities.txt", "r") as infile:
    cities = [city.rstrip('\n') for city in infile]
```

If you *really* want a dictionary, then convert the list to a dictionary, using index as a key:

```
cities = []
with open("cities.txt", "r") as infile:
    cities = [city.rstrip('\n') for city in infile]

citydict = {index: city for index, city in enumerate(cities)}
```

Comment: yes thank you, that worked! I did only need a list, but I at first couldn't find a way to add to it using the loop, so thanks for killing two birds with one stone

Comment: `cities = []` line is not required.